# Can someone enlighten me on where there needs to be a parenthesis?

Tags: java

I run the code and it is showing me errors that java: ')' Expected on lines 19-24. I am not sure where those are supposed to go because it looks to me like everyone is closed off. I am very new to coding with java. Thank you so much if you can help me. I am using intellij.

```
customers.add(new Customer("Tyler",234, b:"good"));
        //printQueue(customers);
        Customer x=new Customer("Tony",999,b:"good"));
        customers.add(new Customer("Kate",123, b:"bad"));
        customers.add(new Customer("MacKenzie",432, b:"good"));
        customers.add(new Customer("Sydney",476, b:"good"));
```

Comment: This line seems to have an extra closing parenthesis `Customer x=new Customer("Tony",999,b:"good"));` - you can remove the last one

Comment: What is the b:"good" notation? I think that might produce an error of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

1. `b: "good"` is not java. Java does not have named parameters.
2. The third line in your paste has 1 opening paren, and 2 closing ones.

`Customer x = new Customer("Tony", 999,b:"good"));`

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to have an extra closing parenthesis

```
Customer x=new Customer("Tony",999,b:"good"));
```

- you can remove the last one.

However, I think the issue is that you have this extra letter `b` in the constructor and that does not match the syntax.

Can you try removing the `b:` in each of the lines you are creating a new Customer? like:

```
Customer x=new Customer("Tony",999,"good");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Customer x=new Customer("Tony",999,b:"good"));
```

Hi, seems like in the line above there is an extra `)` at the end. Try to remove it